# Вставка html в angularjs

Tags: html, angularjs

С помощью php+mysql+angular достаю из базы значения и обрабатываю их.
Возникла сложность при обработке html-тегов в тексте, загружаемом из бд.
Пытаюсь обработать html таким образом, но безуспешно:

```
<div ng-repeat="x in names">
<div ng-bind-html="x.Reply">{{ x.Reply }}</div>
```

Есть варианты, как можно обработать html-код? Сейчас текст выводится вместе с тегами (без обработки html).

Comment: Вот так выводится, почему, не знаю.   http://plnkr.co/edit/PLlzEfVKeVDDjS9Bx45V?p=preview

Comment: <span ng-bind-html="x.Reply" class="Reply"></span>
Делаю так, по аналогии, но безрезультатно. Может быть, у Вас еще какие-нибудь обработчики повешены?

Comment: Ну. там подрублен некий sanetize и фигурирует какой-то $sce.

http://www.slideshare.net/joshs633/angular-js-strict-contextual-escaping-sce - может, чем поможет.

Comment: Да-да, вот тоже заметил, уже начал копать в этом направлении... Спасибо еще раз)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Примерно вот так должен выглядеть код в ангуляре, соотвественно в $scope.myHTML должны передаваться ваши данные из базы:

```
angular.module('bindHtmlExample', [])
.controller('ExampleController', ['$scope', '$sce', function($scope, $sce) {
  $scope.sce = $sce;
  $scope.myHTML =
     'I am an <code>HTML</code>string with ' +
     '<a href="#">links!</a> and other <em>stuff</em>';
}]);
```

А вот так переменная должна выводиться в HTML:

```
<body ng-app="bindHtmlExample">
    <div ng-controller="ExampleController">
   <p ng-bind-html="sce.trustAsHtml(myHTML)"></p>
  </div>
</body>
```

Именно такой способ вам подойдёт, чтобы выводить значения из базы с правильной интерпретацией html.

Comment: @MasterAlex, спасибо, но не могли бы Вы поподробнее подсказать? Если честно, я не совсем понимаю, куда её засунуть.
У меня был такой код:

    <script>
    function customersController($scope,$http) {
        $http.get("quest.php")
        .success(function(response) {$scope.names = response;});
   }
    </svript>

Меня конкретно интересует, как задать в контроллере $scope и связать все это с $sce, если до этого просто присваивался результат выполнения скрипта.

Comment: По идее вот так должен выглядеть контроллер и не забудьте добавить в html sce: <script>
function customersController($scope,$http,$sce) { $scope.sce = $sce;
$http.get("quest.php") .success(function(response) {$scope.names = response;}); }
</script>

Comment: @MasterAlex, все работает! Огромное Вам спасибо!